# Can all covector field be written as a product of a function and a differential of another function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Is it available to write every covector field

$$
\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha^i\mathrm dx_i
$$
on a manifold into the form
$$
\alpha = f\mathrm{d}g,
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are smooth functions? Or, can we do this at least locally?

Comment: In the (simplest) case where $\alpha$ is non-vanishing, this is true if $n = 2$ (because line fields are locally integrable) and not if $n > 2$ (a [contact structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry) in three-space is not locally integrable; pullbacks by coordinate projection give higher-dimensional examples).

Answer (score 4):

Your question is about whether there is an integrating factor ($1/f$ in your notation). In the two-dimensional case, there is always an integrating factor (this is essentially equivalent to existence of solutions to the differential equation $\alpha=0$. But already in 3D you are in trouble. In that case, there is an integrating factor only if $\alpha\wedge d\alpha=0$. So the answer to your question would be: yes in 2D, not in general if $n\ge 3$.